# How to Play AudioServicesPlaySystemSound When iPhone is Silenced

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, audio

I'm making an iOS game with Swift and trying to play system sounds when the iPhone is silenced so that you can hear sound effects regardless of volume mode. The code to play the sound is:

```swift
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1000)
```

This works fine when the iPhone has the volume rocker unmuted; however, if the phone is silenced, nothing plays. If I change this to:

```swift
AudioServicesPlayAlarmSound(1000)
```

I get vibrating on silent mode but not the audio. I've seen examples of how to setup the AppDelegate to change the audio mode like the following:

```swift
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch {
            #if DEBUG
                print("ERROR: Cannot play music in background: \"\(error)\"")
            #endif
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

However, I'm using iOS 15 and `AppDelegate` isn't really necessary anymore. What's a modern way I can play system sounds regardless of the volume state in my game? No other answers on the site worked for me.

Comment: You need to set the playback category. You don't have to do it in the app delegate, but app delegate is still available with the SwiftUI lifecycle

Comment: @Paulw11 is that not what I've done above? Can you provide a simple code snippet to showcase doing so?

Comment: You have. Are you are this code is executing?

Comment: Yeah, I added a print statement which outputs after successfully entering the try section.

Comment: I think this playback mode probably only has an effect when you play your own sound via the AV framework, not a system sound. I suspect that there is no way for playsystemsound to override the mute switch.

Comment: Dang, I was afraid of that. Apple didn't appear to list that caveat in their docs, do we have proof of documentation that states system sounds always respect the volume rocker and cannot be overridden? I

Comment: I think you have proved it . I would spect system sounds to honour the silence switch. You can playback your own sounds